# My code works on Replit, but when I try to run it on console, it says "Times Out". Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

**My Code**

> Please tell me if I can solve this problem in any other ways

```
  function isOddWithoutModulo(num) {
      
      let result = num;
      
      while(result!==0&&result!==1){
          
          result=Math.floor(result/2);
            
      }
      if(result===1){
          return true;
      }
      
      return false;
    }
    isOddWithoutModulo(100007)
```

Comment: Hi, I copy-paste your code snippet into my chrome console and it works fine.